# Why do we usually multiply an audio signal in log scale by 20?

Tags: audio, signal-processing

Here is a quite elementary question in audio processing.

After a signal is converted in log scale, it is usually multiplied by 20. Inversely, to recover some gain in linear scale, we use the formula

```
G_linear = 10 ** (0.05 * G_in_dB)
```

This makes sense because 0.05 is 1/20.

But where does this **20** factor comes from? What is the theory behind it?

I read some courses and code for signal processing, but have not found any explanation for this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The wiki page seems to cover it all:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a decibel of gain multiplies the signal *power* by a factor of 10<sup>1/10</sup>.

Linear gain applies to *amplitude*, not power, though.

Since power = amplitude<sup>2</sup>, a decibel of gain multiplies the signal *amplitude* by (10<sup>1/10</sup>)<sup>1/2</sup> = 10<sup>1/20</sup>